# Undefined arguments using async.apply inside of async.series

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am using the async library inside of my project and I end up with a strange behavior : some of my arguments are "undefined" in my call.

For example (this is not my actual code but the behavior is the same and it is simpler to expose my problem this way) :

```
var token;

async.series([
    function getToken (done) {
        api.getToken(userId, function (err, data) {
            if (err) return done(err);
            token = data;
            return done();
        }
    },
    async.apply(doSomethingWithTheToken, token)
], callback);
```

When my function "doSomethingWithTheToken" is called, the token passed as an argument has an "undefined" value, even if I changed it in my previous function "getToken".

But if I do :

```
var token;

async.series([
    function getToken (done) {
        api.getToken(userId, function (err, data) {
            if (err) return done(err);
            token = data;
            return done();
        }
    },
    function doSomething (done) {
        doSomethingWithTheToken(token, done);
    }
], callback);
```

Then no problem my token passed in the function "doSomethingWithTheToken" has the correct value given by the previous function.

I've done a little bit of research in the async module before writing this post and when I display the arguments passed to the async.apply function, surprise they are displayed before any function call made in the async.series flow - which explains why my token value is "undefined".

Is anyone able to explain me why is this behavior happening ?

I hope I've been clear with my issue
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

whenever async.series called, it prepares its all function references within an array, 
it adds getToken in array,
then calls async.apply and it adds generated function reference (output of async.apply) in array.

At that time token was undefined.

Scenarios happening here like this:

```
> var i;

> var arr = [1,2,3,i,5,6];

> i=4;

> arr
[ 1, 2, 3, undefined, 5, 6 ]
```

Hope you understand this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I understand now, but it means I don't have a way to simply use "async.apply" inside of this kind of flow where the value of arguments might change in the execution ?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the other answer: at the moment `async.apply` is called `token` is `undefined`.

You might want to look into [`async.waterfall`](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall) though, it allows you to pass arguments to the next function in the sequence, which allows you to do this:

```
async.waterfall([
    function getToken (done) {
        api.getToken(userId, function (err, data) {
            if (err) return done(err);
            return done(null, data);
        });
    },
    function doSomething (token, done) {
        doSomethingWithTheToken(token, done);
    }
  ], callback);
```

In fact you can shorten it to this (if `doSomethingWithTheToken` accepts `token` and `done` as parameters):

```
async.waterfall([
    function getToken (done) {
        api.getToken(userId, done);
    },
    doSomethingWithTheToken
  ], callback);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm aware of async.waterfall but in my case it does not really feet my needs (the real code is more complex than this example) and I wanted to user async.apply to make the code looks more clear. Anyway I've got the point, thanks again for the quick answer.